# Pulling SQL Server service info in PowerShell, Escaping $ sign powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

how can I escape a variable being passed to get-service ? I'm passing $_.NAME and this name will contain $(dollar) sign in it causing it to fail.

How can I tell powershell to not consider the $ inside of that variable and pass it to get-service and still work ?

```
foreach($machine in $machines) {    
    Write-Output "$machine ACTIVE NOW: "    
    Write-Output "---------------------------------"
    Get-Service -name "*sql*" -computername $machine -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
        Sort-Object -Property DisplayName   |
        foreach{
            $k = $machine + " - " + $_.DisplayName
            $v = $_Status
            $serviceStatus[$k] = $v

            Get-Service `$_.Name | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ServicesDependedOn | 
            foreach{ 
                $kd = $k + "has a dependency on " + $_.DisplayName
                $s  = $_.Status
                $serviceStatus[$kd] = $s
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the escape character '\' ? Also, not sure what this has to do with databases...?

Comment: Just for those trying to close this question, it actually does not belong on SO. If anything this question could be moved to SF however there are other questions on DBA.SE that reference managing SQL Server services (whether you are just pulling information or troubleshooting)...so it is does fall into [what can be asked on this site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @ShawnMelton: I don't know if this question would be on-topic on SF but I believe it's perfectly fine for SO and to a greater extent than for DBA.SE. And I don't believe that merely because PowerShell is a universal (rather than DB-specific) scripting environment but because the problem in question is generic and not DB-specific.

Answer (score 4):

You should not have to escape anything when with your script, it should work if you remove the back-tick with `$_.Name`.

PowerShell is smart enough to accept values with special characters as literal values when you are passing the property using the method in your script. If you wrapped it in double-quotes `"$_.Name"` then SQL Server would try to evaluate the expression and only pass the `MSSQL`  of your instance service name.

This command runs without any error on my machine:

```
Get-Service -name "*SQL*" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
 sort-object -Property DisplayName | 
 foreach { Get-Service $_.Name | select -ExpandProperty ServicesDependedOn}
```

[image]